# Implementing Safe Areas for Tab Bar Controller and iPhone X

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

**What I'm trying to do:** place the tab bar at the bottom of the iPhone X display where it belongs, and also put the navigation bar at the top of the display.

I've been trying to accomplish what I thought would be a straightforward task of using Safe Areas in the storyboard to position the tab bar near the bottom of the iPhone X's display. I'm missing something fundamental.

I've read a lot of writeup about how to do this, [including this one](https://novemberfive.co/blog/apple-september-event-iphonex-apps/). It includes a screenshot of a tab bar control scene that looks like this:
[image]

**But I can't create a view inside my Tab Bar Controller to put my tab bar item in**, as the article mentions. It's my understanding that I'll use the safe area of the view that should contain the tab bar item. But it won't let me put a view anywhere except outside the Controller view.  I've tried using "embed" - but all options are greyed out.

Same goes for a navigation controller to move a navigation bar to the top of the display.

The funny thing is that IB renders it in the right place, but on my device, the tab bar is way above where it should be (and the navigation bar way below).

[image]

I have "Opens in" set to "Latest Xcode (9.0) and Builds for iOS 11.1 set in the scene's "Interface Builder Document", and "use Safe Area Layout Guides" is checked. I'm not using any custom classes for my tab bar controller or tab bar. I'm using XCode 9.3 and iOS 11.3.1

What's the simple thing that I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

[image][image]

Comment: if you can elaborate what you want to achieve that would be great.

Comment: Sorry - I thought it was implicit - I need the tab bar at its proper place at the bottom of the iPhone X display (will edit post).

Comment: then you'll not be able to tap the tabbar buttons.

Comment: The proper bottom of the iPhone X display just where the white bar is. That's where tab bars appear nominally, not where this screenshot shows them.

Answer (score 1):

The article explains how to adapt your app if you're using a custom navigation bar or a custom tab bar.

If you're using the standard navigation bar or tab bar then you have to make sure it's top or bottom (depending on the element) constraints are connected to the **superview** and **not** the **Safe Area layout guide**. UIKit makes sure these elements are correctly rendered with spacing at the top or bottom on an iPhone X device. Check out [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww4kP.png) for clarification.

Comment: thanks - the problem is - I can't even put constraints or align anything with the tab bar; everything is greyed out. (I'm not using a custom tab bar). I'm assuming this is because there's notning to align it to? I can't put a UIView in there and put the Tab Bar inside. I can't control-drag the tab bar to anything except the tab bar controller, and that just gives me an option to add a delegate outlet.

I can't even put the tab bar inside a view to even get a safe area to attach to even if I wanted to.

Otherwise, the tab bar functions normally in the app

Comment: @yodel It seems that you're using a standard _Tab Bar Controller_ in which case it's normal everything is greyed out. It's not possible to add views, constraints or anything else here. It's only possible to add a tab bar in a regular view controller. Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: The strange thing is I do have a Tab Bar inside a Tab Bar Controller (the tab bar controller is my initial view controller)- it works fine  - but I can't put any constraints on anything as I mentioning, and there are no safe areas. I've updated the original post with two other screenshots - one of the storyboard, and one of the view controller stack I'm referring to.

How should I structure this? I can't seem to embed a tab bar controller into anything.

Comment: So I had to put this project in a drawer for awhile, but got it out and did some testing, and things keep getting stranger. 

Tab View Controllers now work properly with iPhone X models - I tested that out with a new project. It puts the tabs where they're supposed to be at the bottom. But my project still puts them in this misplaced position.

I created a new storyboard with a new tab view controller , going to a blank viewcontroller. I created a new "blank" app delegate as well to make sure it wasn't something in there doing it. And the project *still* places it in wrong place

Comment: So, as I've been editing this project over the past 4 years here and there, the only thing I can think of is that the culprit is somewhere in the project settings.

Is there somewhere in the build settings, etc where I should check? Can't find anything as I've combed through them. Any ideas?